# iPhone deployment management

Tags: iphone, deployment

I have a little app that I want (potentially) a lot of my clients to test and give feedback on before launch, do I really need to setup a massive list of UUID's in the provisioning profile and build against that certificate, email them the .APP file and the certificate?

I was hoping for a, perhaps, private app store? But I cannot seem to find much on this topic

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated here :)

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that even with the Enterprise option, you'll still need to distribute a provisioning profile:

http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf (particularly Chapter 5)

However, it looks like you won't need to add each device to this provisioning profile if it's an Enterprise profile, but the users themselves (or the IT support staff) would have to add the provisioning profile to each machine with iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Without Enterprise profile, unfortunately the answer is YES. And with enterprise profile, the scenario is already explained in previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

If they all have iPhone SDK installed in their Mac, and if your app doesn't require device-specific features (camera, accelerometer...) then you can just zip your app folder in your iPhone simulator's Application Support folder and send it to all your clients.

It works great for a number of my clients, especially to validate the user interface.